# [Slick2D + LWJGL]How to invert the mouse x and y directions

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl, axis, slick2d

I recently got into Slick2D and Java game development and I've come across a "dead end" in my programming skills. I wish to invert the x and y axis (or only x/only y) for the mouse direction, so if the user moves his mouse upwards, the cursor would go downwards, if he moves it to the left, the cursor goes towards the right etc.
After doing some thorough research, it doesn't seem like people wish to do this quite often and I haven't found any relevant information.
I don't think showing my code is necessary since there isn't anything related to what I wish to do in it, but if you need to see it I will be happy to comply.

(Furthermore, another problem came to mind: the cursor would go outside the window and unfocus the program if the user clicks, is there a way to "imprison" the mouse/cursor inside an area in the window? So the user wouldn't be able to leave the window, unless he presses escape to open the pause state etc.)

Since I am still a novice with Slick2D and Java in general, if you could be very specific in your answers by telling me where my code should be modified (init, render, update...) That would be delightful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert a any integer or float you can always do this `B = (A *= -1)` the B is an inverted/negated version of A.
In case of the mouse it would look something like this.

```
int RegularMouseX = Mouse.getX();
int InvertedMouseX = (RegularMouseX *= -1);
```

Asuming you get the new mouse position in the update method like any sane person would do. Recreate or re-set the inverted mouse variable every update after getting the mouse Position.